# Bootstrap vue on:blur handler is not been called

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have the following component

```
<template>
  <b-input :value="value" @blur="validateEmail" ref="input" :state="state"/>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

    methods: {
      validateEmail: function() {
      console.log('test')
    },

  }
</script>
```

The method validateEmail is not been triggered when input loses focus.

Comment: do you try change `b-input` to `input` ?

Comment: I have changed the b-input to input and it works indeed, but this is not an option for me since I need to use b-input. Thanks.

Comment: may be `b-form-input` is an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change @blur to @change and it will work.