# Vue bootstrap on blur event

Tags: vue.js

I am not able to use vue on blur event, 
In my component I have a `@change` directive

```
<b-input :value="value" @change="validateEmail($event)" @input="$emit('input', $event)" ref="input" :state="state"/>
```

This is because `@blur` doesn't seem to work.
[Bootstrap vue on:blur handler is not been called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207177/bootstrap-vue-onblur-handler-is-not-been-called/53207382#53207382)

This works partially when I am changing the input and hit tab, then works, but if I focus on the input and click tab without changing the input, it doesn't work. 
I want to show a message that email is required in this case but I cannot.

Comment: Did you try `@blur.native="..."`? Never tried, but since your b-input is a vue component, it may be related with native events.

Answer (score 5):

You may use `@blur.native` with Bootstrap Vue inputs.

```
<b-input
        :value="value"
        @change="validateEmail($event)"
        @input="$emit('input', $event)"
        ref="input"
        :state="state"

        @blur.native="handleBlur"

/>
```

https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1645#issuecomment-369477878

Answer (score 1):

you can use `@blur.native="function"`

Comment: You should add a link to the documentation to spice up your anwer!